# Eclipse uml to c++ tool? and how to document code?

Tags: c++, eclipse

hi i have two questions about c++ development in eclipse

1. is there a free tool whitch generate c++ code from UML diagrams?
2. how must i comment code in c++ that i see the documentation in the tooltip? (in java i write "/**" over the function and press enter and the documentation template is generatet automaic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first point I redirect you to [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/). This free UML design tool has a C++ add-in that can generate C++ code from the diagrams.